# mongod runs with command but not with config file

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, process

I am trying to start `mongod` with a config file on MongoDB 3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04. I can launch mongod by issuing the command myself, but I can't get it to work with the config file.

Here's the command I'm issuing:

`sudo mongod --replSet rs0 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --dbpath /data/db --storageEngine wiredTiger --fork`

When I run this command, I can then run `mongo` to enter the mongo shell and successfully use the database.

I don't see a difference between the command I'm issuing and the config file, which I call with `sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. When I run this, and try a command in the same `mongo` shell I had successfully used for the prior query, I get

```
2017-01-31T10:55:44.899-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:689:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:118:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:276:5
DBCollection.prototype.findOne@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:289:10
@(shell):1:1
```

and here is my `/etc/mongod.conf`. How are these different?:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: "/data/db"
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: "wiredTiger"
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


processManagement:
  fork: true

#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rs0
#  oplogSizeMB: 1024

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message "not master and slaveOk=false" is what you get when you try to query on a [secondary server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/#replica-set-secondary-members). If you're getting that message, that implies that:

1. The server has successfully started
2. The server has successfully joined the replica set
3. A different server is currently Primary

You should be able to check that by running `rs.status()` in the shell (assuming your user account has [replicaset administration privileges](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.replSetGetStatus)).

If you want to run a query on this server to confirm that it is working (even though it is currently a secondary), you can use the [rs.slaveOk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.slaveOk/) call.