# How to connect via config file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongodb-3.6

In config file I have:

```
   systemLog:
        destination: file
        logAppend: true
        path: c:\data\log\mongod.log
    storage:
        dbPath: c:\data\db
        journal:
            enabled: true
    replication:
       replSetName: "rs0"
    net:
       bindIp: 127.0.0.1
       port: 27017
    security:
         authorization: enabled
```

[image]

I'm trying to connect using `mongod` process like in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file):

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin> mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db --config C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg
```

And getting:

> Error reading config file: No such file or directory
>   try 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe --help' for more information

[image]

Then trying with quotes

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin> mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg"
```

and getting:

> 2018-07-02T02:49:21.272+0300 I CONTROL  [main] log file "c:\data\log\mongod.log" exists; moved to "c:\data\log\mongod.log.2018-07-01T23-49-21".

[image]
Starting `mongo`, then `show dbs` and see: [image]

If I'm writting this snippet (without config), everything is fine:

```
mongod --auth --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

[image]
With `mongo`: 
[image]
What I'm doing wrong? I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you use --config, you don't need those other parameters, because your config have those already.

Comment: I think there are some missing information here. The config you posted says that you're running a replica set node, but only one of them. This will put them into `SECONDARY` status, and the reason why you need `rs.slaveOk()` to query it. What is your goal? Are you trying to run MongoDB for development? Where did you get the steps from?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha not yet, just learning now. the goal is to learn more about the possibilities of technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

1. To avoid the error like: `not master and slaveOk = false` need always using the command: [`rs.slaveOk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990428/8370915).
2. To avoid typing rs.slaveOk() every time need to add `rs.slaveOk()` in `.mongorc.js` file [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623540/8370915) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#files)
3. More detail [information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165444/153538).